# Quests not marked as completed under achievements?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I've just completed Act 1 - and looking at the achievements, it seems there are several which have not awarded because the requisites have been marked as not completed.

For example: The Last of the Horadrim Achievement which says complete all quests in Act 1, has few quests marked as incomplete even though I I'm pretty sure I've completed them.

Why is this so?

[image: achievement list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servers, overburdened as they were, had a hard time synchronizing all achievements the first few days after release.

[Official Blizzard response](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149005931?page=5#89)

I had the same issue, and actually had to redo some bosses in Act I to get the "kill boss X" achievement.

Comment: I have the achievements for lvl 10, 30, and 40. But I missed the one for lvl 20.